# Android: How to access resources folder from other android application

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I've integrated jar in my application. The jar contains images and strings. I'm able to access images and string from that jar programmatically but i need to access resources from jar in xml files

**Programmatically:**

```
imgView.setImageResource(com.example.jartesting.R.drawable.call_icon);
```

The above code works fine.

**XML**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagesample"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@com/example/jartesting/drawable/call_icon"/>
```

The above xml code is not working. It showing **Error: String types not allowed**

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: aren't you supposed to prefix it with @drawable ? I mean
@drawable/com.example.jartesting.drawable.call_icon

Comment: Hi if i'm using the above line its showing "Error: No resource found that matches the given name"

Comment: Can you pls try with this. Last trial !! 
@com.example.jartesting:drawable/call_icon

Comment: @Ramesh. Its showing same error

Comment: S i tried its shwoing same error

Comment: is quite mistaken. The JAR contains only code; you can reuse as modules in android studio

Answer (score 0):

The JAR contains only code; you cannot access resources that way.

For ex:  Google distributes their own "Google Play Services Library" as an Android library project, containing the binary code in a JAR file in the lib directory, the resources in the res directory, and an UnusedStub class in the src directory. If a better approach were viable yet I think they'd be using it.

While Android Studio is still in beta, it includes (buggy) support for [AAR](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) files. Seems this will eventually be the way to go.